# Jboss Pausing AJP port

Tags: apache, sockets, jboss, ajp

I'm trying to connect Apache WS to JBoss via AJP protocol. The problem is that JBoss pauses the binding for the ajp port.

Here's the log:

```
[JBoss Shutdown Hook] : AjpProtocol - Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8081
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JBoss version is 4.2. Apache connects to a different Tomcat via AJP without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by disabling HTTPS connector on port 8443.